# How to get specific container from init containers in kubernetes?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have the following code:

```
config.load_incluster_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
my_init_containers = v1.read_namespaced_pod(namespace=NAMESPACE, name=pod_name).spec.init_containers
```

This gives me all the containers in `init_containers`. My problem is that I want to get only specific container: `git-sync-init-container`.

I can do:

```
init = v1.read_namespaced_pod( namespace=NAMESPACE, name=pod_name).spec.init_containers[2]
```

But I don't want to use indexes. How can I get a container by name?
I tried to iterate over `my_init_containers` searching for `name=git-sync-init-container` but this is a `V1Container` type and it doesn't let me iterate over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close:

```py
my_init_containers = v1.read_namespaced_pod(namespace=NAMESPACE, name=pod_name).spec.init_containers
for container in my_init_containers:
    if container.name == "the_one_im_looking_for":
        init = container
        break
```